# Is it acceptable to always use pointers instead of references, to be easily converted to smart pointers if needed?

Tags: c++

I know references are preferred over pointers, but it is very tedious to change all those "." to "->" when needed. So is it an acceptable practice to always use pointers instead of references, to be easily convert them to smart pointers if needed? Or is there any way to quickly change a reference to pointer?

Comment: Side note: Changing `variable.func()` to `variable->func()` could easily be done by doing a find-replace from `variable.` to `variable->`.

Comment: @chris, that's the tedious part :) You also may have to select the whole function first to perform "Find & replace only selected text".

Answer (score 15):

> So is it an acceptable practice to always use pointers instead of references, to be easily convert them to smart pointers if needed

No. In general, **always** rules are always bad. (including this one). Why would you want to convert a reference to a smart pointer? If it's a reference, you don't need to worry about memory management, and that's the purpose of a smart pointer.

> Or is there any way to quickly change a reference to pointer?

Yes, taking it's address (`&`).

Comment: _Always_ rules are _always_ bad, including this one :) +1

Comment: Thanks, why would I want to convert a reference to a smart pointer? It happens when I can't decide what to pass to a method, a reference, a pointer or a smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the architecture just to facilitate text replacements in source code?

**No**, this is never a valid design decision. And as Luchian has explained, this doesn’t seem like a really existing consideration to begin with.

Comment: Please don't use a script. Or even find and replace all. Search and replace one by one so you can be sure of everything you change.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I think a script is entirely safe. If it messes something up, the result will not compile.

Comment: The danger is when it does. I've burned myself with that kind of stuff before - thank God for version control.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi In this case it's probably okay, since replacing `.` with `->` is only going to compile if it's the right replacement to do. I don't see any runtime errors that can come out of doing this automatically.

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right for a dumb pointer. The problem arises with a smart pointer when a method is available for both `->` and `.`

Comment: @Mahmoud I just realised that, hence the edit. Oh, and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers instead of references will not make later conversion to smart pointers any easier.  You can't just replace all pointers with smart pointers and expect anything to work; the semantics of smart pointers is significantly different from that of pointers (and usually not what you want).

Using pointers instead of references in classes with value semantics does make sense, since it's difficult, if not impossible, to implement the expected assignment semantics with references.  Smart pointers have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Difficult to implement assignment semantics *with* references?  Or *without*?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It depends on what the pointer is used for.  If it is for variable sized data, you need a deep copy; it isn't necessarily trivial to implement the semantics with a pointer, but it's impossible with a reference.  If the pointer is used for navigation, however (generally rare in objects with value semantics, but there are exceptions), then the default `operator=` does the job (and again, the correct semantics can't be implemented using a reference).

Comment: Oh, okay.  I misunderstood you.  I didn't know you were referring to data members.  I thought you were referring to the parameter of the assignment operator and you just made a typo.

Answer (score -1):

The point of using references is to make things slightly easier for you because you can use them like a regular, non-pointer variables.

But if it's not easier, or even harder, I see absolutely no reason to use them.

There's nothing wrong with using pointers.

Comment: Sorry folks, but the comments here don't seem to reach any sort of resolution.

Comment: If I had it wouldn't still be here :)